# How to store the value of a jquery output in input tag

Tags: jquery

I need to store on whatever the value of this  $('#uploaded_image') to the input data  May I know how can I be able to do it?

```
<input name="string" hidden> </input>

success:function(data)
{
 $('#uploaded_image').html(data);
```

Comment: input type hidden? wright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an id for the input and set the data value to Input element.e.g.below

$("#Inputval").val(data);

Answer (score 0):

I think input type hidden

```
success:function(data)
{
 $('#uploaded_image').val(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

As if you want to store the value on that input tag you can do, something like.

```
$("input[name=string]").val(data);
```